# When using amplify, where is my Cognito User Pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm setting up my first amplify project for a JS app, working through the getting started documentation [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication). After running `amplify add auth` and configuring a new cognito user pool, with no problems, and running `amplify push` with no problems. I cannot find the new cognito pool anywhere in the AWS console. I've looked through every region, and I've tried logging in to the console as my amplify IAM user, and I see nothing – both in the cognito section or cloudformation section.

So... where is it? Has it not been created yet? Do amplifty user pools not appear in the console?

Comment: Can you interact with this pool using amplify? Did you get any pool id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bob,

Kindly check your Amplify logs to see what has really happened. If configuration and provisioning are successful, Amplify will write the configurations in aws-exports.js. if you cannot find the file, simply fire > grep "userPoolId:" . -r

Robin

Comment: By checking aws-exports.js, I found that I had set the region to eu-west-2, not us-west-2. It never occurred to me to check non-US regions  TL;DR - I am dumb.